# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{∞}e^{-\frac{an}{x}}=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

I am asking, why does
$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞}e^{-\frac{an}{x}}=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1}$$
(where 'a' is just an arbitrary constant)
Is it to do with power series expansion of the terms, or something else?

Comment: Have you already heard about geometric series?

Comment: Note that for $|z|<1$, we have $1+z^2+z^3+\cdots=1/(1-z)$

Comment: It's just a geometrical series $\frac{1}{1-x}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k $

Comment: oops, I'm dumb, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fact: for $x$ such that $|x| < 1$, one has $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1$. Now use this formula with $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a}{x}}$ in place of $x$.

Comment: One small thing: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} - 1$, not $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Other than that, this explanation hits the nail on the head.

Comment: @AlannRosas Thanks! I typed it fast and it has now been corrected!